# Http метод (POST) @RequestMapping или @PostMapping?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, rest

Изучаю Spring по туториалу, но он 2016 года, я увидел вот такое:
Вот такой Post метод

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/topics")
    public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic){
        topicService.addTopic(topic);
    }
```

Пишу с нуля сам. Но увидел вот такой пример Post метода в обучающем проекте компании:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
public ResponseEntity<ClientDTO> createClient(@RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO) {
    System.out.println("create");
    return clientServiceImpl.createNewClient(clientDTO);
}
```

Какие различия у этих 2 методов? 
**UPD!!!** 
Какой из этих вариантов нужно использовать в плане поддержки и правильности кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Различий - никаких, просто для удобства добавили `@PostMapping`.
Если откроете исходники, то увидите следующее:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @interface PostMapping {

/**
 * Alias for {@link RequestMapping#name}.
 */
@AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
String name() default "";
.......
}
```

Некоторые статические анализаторы кода, типа Sonar, могут ругаться на использование `RequestMapping`

Используйте `@PostMapping` и будет Вам счастье (но это не точно:))

Comment: Что такое статические анализаторы кода? Своими словами можно не очень понял суть из википедии

Comment: В двух словах, они анализируют исходный код на предмет потенциальных багов, уязвимостей, плохого стиля и т.д.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван дополнил ответ, в соответствии с Вашей правкой